# Javascript - Continue statement not working?

Tags: javascript, html, break, continue, statements

Im currently learning about *break* and *continue* statements. It prints the 1st array, the 2nd array runs the alert like it suppose to, but the third one doesn't run, when i use the *continue* statement. Maybe im not doing it right? some guidance for a newbie would be nice.

Im using JSBin to run this.

p.s. im learning from the "Begining Javascript" book

Thanks

```js
var n = [233, "john", 432];
var nIndex;

for (nIndex in n) {
    if (isNaN(n[nIndex])) {
        alert(n[nIndex] + " is not a number");
        continue;
    }
    document.write(n[nIndex] + " ");
}
```

Comment: I didn't find any problem in your code . it working fine.

Comment: FYI, you should never iterate javascript arrays with `for (x in y)` because that will iterate all enumerable `properties` of the array, not just array elements which could include no array element properties.  You should use either `.forEach()` or `for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)`.

Comment: What are you expecting to see? We see '233' being written to the console, then an alert box saying 'john is not a number', then 432 written again to the console.

Comment: Everything is fine on my side.

Comment: In which browser? Note that *for..in* doesn't necessarily iterate over the properties in any particular order.

Comment: @Dave Walker Yea I got the 233 on console, and the alert box, but I didn't get the 432, so I don't get why

Comment: If you click the 'Run code snippet' on your sample code (above) then you get the result you want. If you are not getting that then you have something else going on in whatever it is you are doing. Can you try running that and see what you get?.

Answer (score 2):

Continue does not work in :

```
for(i in  array) {}
```

it  works for `for(i=0; i<n; i++){}`

Answer (score 0):

This is how you iterate over the elements of an array:

```js
var data = [233, "john", 432];

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    if (isNaN(data[i])) {
        alert(data[i] + " is not a number");
        continue;
    }
    document.write(data[i] + " ");
}
```

By the way, you can remove the `continue` statement and instead use `else` on the alternate instructions:

```js
    var data = [233, "john", 432];

    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
        if (isNaN(data[i])) {
            alert(data[i] + " is not a number");
        } else {
            document.write(data[i] + " ");
        }
    }
```

That's logically equivalent and you may find it easier to read.